# Group Django queryset into separate sections depending on choice

Tags: python, django

I've got the following Django model:

```
class Product(models.Model):

    HARDWARE = 'H'
    SOFTWARE = 'S'
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        (HARDWARE, 'Hardware'),
        (SOFTWARE, 'Software'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default=HARDWARE)
```

I'd like to display all products in a template, separated into Hardware and Software.

```
{% for category in grouped_by_category %}
    <h1>{{category.name}}</h1>
    <ul>
    {% for product in category.products %}
        <li>{{product.name}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

This is what I have, but it just seems inefficient.

```
def grouped_by_category():
    grouped_products = []
    all_products = Product.objects.all()
    for key, name in Product.CATEGORY_CHOICES:
        category_products = []
        for product in all_products:
            if product.category == key:
                category_products.append(product)
        grouped_products.append({'name': name, 'products':category_products})
    return grouped_products
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the regroup templatetag in the template:

```
{% regroup all_products by category as grouped_by_category %}

{% for category in grouped_by_category %}
    <h1>{{ category.grouper }}</h1>
    <ul>
    {% for product in category.list %}
        <li>{{product.name}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup for the documentation.

Comment: @Brenden - Likely this is using `itertools.groupby` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) under the hood if you want to do more complicated processing. If you start to run into performance issues rendering too much data, then start with slicing the `Product` query using pagination.

Comment: This worked overall, but ran into a couple issues. They came out sorted in a really weird way, and I wasn't about to figure out the sorting yet. But it feels like a great insight.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different queries based on category

```
def grouped_by_category():
    grouped_products = []
    for key, name in Product.CATEGORY_CHOICES:
        grouped_products.append({'name':name,'products':Product.objects.filter(category=key)})
    return grouped_products
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just hammer the database?

Comment: Yes you're right and I  think @Sam Dolan's answer is better. I only thought, if there is too many record -for example 1.000.000- hit on db is better than iterate in loop.

Comment: I mean, it would just be the number of categories, so in this case only 2 queries, but still, it's best to avoid doing these types of queries unless you can guarantee the number of categories, and that you don't have to do any pagination based on something like timestamps.